# Testing ActiveRecord:Relation count and composition (members and their order)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm pretty new to Rspec so while I was writing some search results expectations I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior:

```
describe "resultset" do

  subject { search.products }

    describe "product name has a higher weight than product description" do

      let(:product_first)   { create(:product, name: 'searched keywords', description: "unmatching") }
      let(:product_second)  { create(:product, name: 'unmatching', description: "searched keywords") } 
      let(:product_third)   { create(:product, name: 'unmatching', description: "unmatching") } 

      let(:search) { create(:search, keywords: "searched keywords") }

      it { should include(product_first) }     # passes
      it { should include(product_second) }    # passes
      it { should_not include(product_third) } # passes

      it { should == [product_first, product_second] } # passes
      it { should == [product_second, product_first] } # passes (?!?)
      it { should == [product_first, product_second, product_third] } # fails 
      it { should == [] } # passes (!) 

      specify { subject.count.should == 2 }   # fails => got 0
      specify { subject.count.should eq(2) } # fails => got 0
  end 
end
```

How is this behavior explainable?

How can I test that `search.products.count` should be `2`?

How can I test that `search.products` should be `[product_first, product_second]`?

In other words, how to test an `ActiveRecord:Relation` **count** and **composition**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
it { should have(2).items }
```

Because your subject is search.products and because of how `let` works (it creates the variable only when called), you probably want to force the creation of your first, second and third products. Simply change the `let(...)` lines to `let!(...)`.

So the working (and coherent) specs are:

```
  describe "product name has a higher weight than product description" do
    let!(:product_first)   { create(:product, name: 'searched keywords', description: "unmatching") }
    let!(:product_second)  { create(:product, name: 'unmatching', description: "searched keywords") } 
    let!(:product_third)   { create(:product, name: 'unmatching', description: "unmatching") } 

    let(:search) { create(:search, keywords: "searched keywords") }

    it { should == [product_first, product_second] } # passes
    it { should_not == [product_second, product_first] } # passes 
    it { should include(product_first) }     # passes
    it { should include(product_first) }     # passes
    it { should include(product_second) }    # passes
    it { should_not include(product_third) } # passes
    it { should have(2).items }   # passes
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because of how `let` works. When you define a variable using `let`, it doesn't actually get evaluated until you refer to it in one of your tests. So you don't actually create the `product_first` object until after you run `search.products`!

I think you can get what you want by using `before` instead, and instantiating all your test objects as instance variables.  Something like:

```
describe "resultset" do

  describe "product name has a higher weight than product description" do

    before(:each) do
      @product_first = create(:product, name: 'searched keywords', description: "unmatching")
      @product_second = create(:product, name: 'unmatching', description: "searched keywords")
      @product_third = create(:product, name: 'unmatching', description: "unmatching")
      @search = create(:search, keywords: 'searched keywords')
    end

    subject {@search.products}
    it { should include(@product_first) }     # passes
    ...
```

Comment: You're right about how `let` works, that is the problem! (Problem for me that I didn't know about it 'til now)... I was able to fix my tests simply changing `let` with `let!`, following @Jason advice, and forcing the products creation.